# Any other ways besides a computed to store a Vue route param such that the reference cannot be modified

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a Vue component where I need to take a route param and pass it along in a couple of XHR requests, and will probably need to use it in other places too.  At first I thought I'd store it as a `data` attribute, but then technically somebody could modify it.

Then I thought to myself, since the route for the screen I'm displaying will not change (a change to the route might result in another screen or a 404), I could make it a computed, it will never be re-computed, and thus the following in effect creates a constant that can be referenced as needed as `this.ID_A`.  Are there other ways to achieve something similar?

```
computed: {
    ID_A() {
        return this.$route.params.id_a;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Are there other ways to achieve something similar?" By trying something.

Comment: That is interesting, based on your older topics :)
Also, I did explain what I tried and got stuck to expanding the logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up vue-router to pass the params as props to the component: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

Comment: Props *could* technically get modified, but that will result in a warning, correct?  I do like the idea.

Comment: Well, if the route changes, then the computed property will also change, so you already have that problem. Yes, if you try to manually change props (or a computed property) you should get a warning.

Comment: If the route changes I will be serving the (SPA) page using a different component

Comment: If you're worried about the user changing the url directly, you can also set up vue-router to obscure the url, using "mode: 'abstract'" in your router index.js and "router.replace('/');" in your main.js

Comment: We do have some concerns about that though not necessarily in this instance but thanks for the information you've been very helpful!